# php pdo error on write, value being set to 0

Tags: php, pdo

```
// Write details to the database
//die("id = ".$country_id); id = au
try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ldm_country (cId, cName) 
                    VALUES(:cty_id, :cty_name)";
    $query = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute( array( ':cty_id'=>$country_id,':cty_name'=>$country_name ) );
} catch (PDOException $err) {  
    echo "Database Issue: " . $err->getMessage();
    $conn = null;
    return;
}
```

When executed am getting

Database Issue: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Yet $country_id has a value of "au"????

Comment: Post the schema definition for your table.

Comment: ID fields in tables are usually integers. Are you sure the 2-letter country code is supposed to go into the `cId` field, not some other field?

Comment: Please execute this command in mysql console or PhpMyAdmin: SHOW CREATE TABLE ldm_country; and post result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem may be that `cId` is an integer field, and `au` is getting coerced into an int, which is being evaluated as 0.

If that's the case, to fix it you'll need to either change the DB field `cId` type to something like varchar, or use an int as the country ID instead.